# Encrypting and Decrypting strings Current Best Practice

Tags: c#

There are a bunch of discussions on here regarding encrypting and decrypting strings but they are all quite a few years old and a lot has changed over the past few years.

For user passwords I use hashing so a password cannot be decrypted.

However, I have a few services I connect to on the back end and need to encrypt a password in a DB so it can be decrypted to run at a later time.

In the past I've used DPAPI.  Is that still the "best" way to store this information in a DB?

Comment: Envelope encryption might  be the latest standard for your scenario.

Answer (score 4):

The best way is "don't do it". If you keep credentials, someone will eventually steal them.

Most back ends have some way of granting an authorization token of some sort that you can use, so you don't need to keep sending a login/password.

There are "new-er" ways of storing credentials like password vaults, secure storage and various types of hardware-based secure storage, but if your program can extract them as plaintext, an attacker can too.

Check into Kerberos Authentication It uses tickets and encrypted mutual authentication to let devices trust each other, without needing to exchange or store plaintext credentials.

If you're on Windows, look into "Integrated Authentication" which usually uses Kerberos.

Comment: I agree with you, unfortunately these are differing systems with custom "access" into them.

Comment: Really, there's nothing good. MS has a SecureString that's better than nothing while in memory, but even they don't recommend it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=netframework-4.7.2 What kind of auth does the other side support?

Comment: Username / password... :(

Comment: Sorry. I've got nothing. Storing UID/PW is like storing toxic waste. It just wants to get out.

Comment: I so agree.. But I'm tasked to link to these systems.

Comment: For storage, SQL Server (and probably others) supports encrypted columns, however you're still left handling plaintext passwords when you actually need to connect to the other system.